# Markers are not showing on min resolution

Tags: openlayers, maps, visibility

Working with Openlayer 6, my map is working fine for the 40 layers on initial load. Against search functionality, I am trying to add a new layer on the map using the following code.

```
const createMarkersLayer = (val)=>{

  const coordinates = val.map(r=>this.getResultCentreCoordinates(r))
  const coordinatesList =  coordinates.flat()
  const markers = new VectorLayer({
  source:new VectorSource(),
  opacity:1,
  visible:true,
  zIndex:100,
  minZoom:3,
  minResolution: 0,
  maxResolution: 100,
  style: new Style({
    image:new Icon({
      src: require('@/mapmanagement/static/images/layers/result-marker.png'),
      opacity: 1,
      size:[200, 200],
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
      scale:1

    })
  })
})
// this.map.getLayers().insertAt(2, markers)
 this.map.addLayer(markers)
 for (let i = 0; i < coordinatesList.length; i++) {
     const marker =  new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(coordinatesList[i])
      })
     markers.getSource().addFeature(marker)
   }}
}
```

**Problem:**

Markers are not visible on min resolution. This last added layer does become visible on max zoom level of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Observed behavior is consequence of your vector source option

```
maxResolution: 100
```

For standard Mercator projection `EPSG:3857` resolution at zoom 10 is 152.8740565703525 and at zoom 11 it's 76.43702828517625. See for example https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/.

Zoom for resolution 100 is 10.61234359549527, and so only after zoom is greater than this value your markers will be displayed.